# regular expression php pregmatch

Tags: php, email, formatting, expression, validating

I have a php regular expression for email formatting. I used this code below

```
if ( !(preg_match('/^\w+@[\w.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$/', $email)) ) : 
$err_email1 = "<div class = 'error'>Sorry, the email is not formatted         properly</div>";
$formerrors = true;
```

However, it doesn't work when there is a period in the email. i.e. John.Smith@mydomain.com. It works fine with JohnSmith@mydomain.com so I know it's the second period.

How can I modify the code so  it works with 2 period? I tried a number of variations but didn't have success.

If you have a good php regular expression site, I am all eyes.

Thanks

Comment: PHP has a built-in regex available per `filter_var()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` which is a lot more real-world-email-address-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

/^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I believe

Comment: It worked, thank you. For the benefit of others, I beleive means [a-z0-9_.-] (to the left of the @ sign)
means you can have any number of dots.

Comment: Thank you. For the benefit of others it is the [a-z0-9_.-] (to the left of the @ sign)
means you can have any number of dots. Many thanks.